# In Angular js, how can I restrict a form submission (or function) to a logged in User only?

Tags: angularjs, authentication, permissions, firebase, angularjs-ng-change

I'm using AngularFire to create a simple Scrum app. Basically, the user can register, add some information, and a user is created in Firebase. I'm using ng-repeat to show all users on a team.html page.

I currently have a function that allows users to click on a "user's tile", which uses ng-route to bring you to that specific user's 'dashboard.html'. My dashboard.html has a few ng-change directives that update the user's 'color' and 'projectDescription' properties - these are tied into the 'DashboardController'.

I want to be able to restrict the updating of a user's status if the 'currentUuser' is not the same as the dashboard.html user. Can someone please give me a hint?

app.js

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', 
['ngRoute', 'firebase', 'appControllers'])
.constant('FIREBASE_URL', 'https://scrumcheck.firebaseio.com/');

// Dependencies
var appControllers = angular.module('appControllers',['firebase']);

myApp.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider){
$routeProvider.
    when('/login', {
        templateUrl: 'views/login.html',
        controller: 'RegistrationController'
    }).
    when('/team', {
        templateUrl: 'views/team.html',
        controller: 'MembersController'
    }).
    when('/views/dashboard/:uId/:mId', {
        templateUrl: 'views/dashboard.html',
        controller: 'DashboardController'
    }).
    when('/register', {
        templateUrl: 'views/register.html',
        controller: 'RegistrationController'
    }).
    otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/login'
    });
}]);
```

authentication.js (factory)

```
myApp.factory('Authentication', function($firebase, 
  $firebaseSimpleLogin, FIREBASE_URL, $rootScope, $location) {

  var ref = new Firebase(FIREBASE_URL);
  var simpleLogin = $firebaseSimpleLogin(ref);

  var myObject = {

    login : function(user) {

      var userRef = new Firebase(FIREBASE_URL + '/users/' + user.uid);
      var userObj = $firebase(userRef).$asObject();

      userObj.$loaded().then(function() {
        $rootScope.currentUser = userObj;
      });

      return simpleLogin.$login('password', {
        email: user.email,
        password: user.password
      });
    }, //login

    register : function(user) {
      return simpleLogin.$createUser(user.email, user.password)
      .then(function(regUser){
        var ref = new Firebase(FIREBASE_URL + 'users');
        var firebaseUsers = $firebase(ref);

        var userInfo = {
          date: Firebase.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP,
          regUser: regUser.uid,
          firstname: user.firstname,
          email: user.email,
              image : "http://telehealth.org/wp-content/images/user-placeholder.jpg",
              color : "plain",
              projectDescription : "Currently working on...",
              yahoo : "yahooIM",
              upcoming : "PTO / WFH / OOO"
        }

        firebaseUsers.$set(regUser.uid, userInfo);
      }); //add user
    }, //register

    logout : function() {
      return simpleLogin.$logout();
    }, //logout

    signedIn: function() {
      return simpleLogin.user != null;
    }

    } //myObject

  //add the function to the rootScope

  $rootScope.signedIn = function() {
    return myObject.signedIn();
  }

  return myObject;
});
```

dashboard.html

```
    <div class="edit" id="frame-{{member.color}}">
        <div id="title-{{member.color}}" class="dashTitle">
        </div>
            <p class="userInfo">{{member.email}} | {{member.yahoo}}</p>
        <div class="dashimage">
            <img ng-src="{{member.image}}" id="frame-{{member.color}}">
        </div>

        <form name="dashColorForm"
            id="dashColorForm"
            novalidate>
            <div class="radio-toolbar">
                <input 
                    type="radio" 
                    id="radio1" 
                    name="radios" 
                    ng-model="color" 
                    ng-change="colorChange(color)"
                    value="green">
              <label for="radio1" id="greenRadio"></label>

              <input 
                type="radio" 
                id="radio2" 
                name="radios" 
                ng-model="color" 
                ng-change="colorChange(color)"
                value="grellow">
              <label for="radio2" id="grellowRadio"></label>

              <input 
                type="radio" 
                id="radio3" 
                name="radios" 
                ng-model="color" 
                ng-change="colorChange(color)"
                value="yellow">
              <label for="radio3" id="yellowRadio"></label>

              <input 
                type="radio" 
                id="radio4" 
                name="radios" 
                ng-model="color" 
                ng-change="colorChange(color)"
                value="orange">
              <label for="radio4" id="orangeRadio"></label>

              <input 
                type="radio" 
                id="radio5" 
                name="radios" 
                ng-model="color" 
                ng-change="colorChange(color)"
                value="red">
              <label for="radio5" id="redRadio"></label>

              <input 
                type="radio" 
                id="radio6" 
                name="radios" 
                ng-model="color" 
                ng-change="colorChange(color)"
                value="darkred">
              <label for="radio6" id="darkredRadio"></label>

              <input 
                type="radio" 
                id="radio7" 
                name="radios" 
                ng-model="color" 
                ng-change="colorChange(color)"
                value="unavailable">
              <label for="radio7" id="unavailableRadio"></label>

            </div>
        </form>

        <form name="dashProjectForm"
            id="projectForm"
            novalidate>
            <div class="dashprojects">
                <textarea 
                    name="projectDescription" 
                    id="memberproject" 
                    ng-model="projectDescription"
                    ng-change="dashProjectUpdate(projectDescription)"
                    placeholder="{{member.projectDescription}}">{{member.projectDescription}}
                </textarea>
            </div>
        </form>
        <p><a class="btn dashsubmit" ng-href="#/team">Go Back</a></p>
    </div>
```

dashboard.js

```
    myApp.controller('DashboardController', 
        function($scope, $firebase, $routeParams, $location, FIREBASE_URL){

        var whichMember = $routeParams.uId;
        var ref = new Firebase(FIREBASE_URL + 'users/'  + whichMember);
        var member = $firebase(ref);

        $scope.member = member.$asObject();

        $scope.colorChange = function() {
            var updateObj = $firebase(ref);

            var updateColor = {
                date: Firebase.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP,
          color : $scope.color
        };

            updateObj.$update(updateColor);
        }

        $scope.dashProjectUpdate = function() {
            var updateObj = $firebase(ref);

            var updateProject = {
                date: Firebase.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP,
          projectDescription : $scope.projectDescription
            };

            updateObj.$update(updateProject);
        }

    });
```

members.json

```
{
  "users" : {
    "simplelogin:1" : {
      "date" : 1410328158691,
      "firstname" : "Adam",
      "image" : "http://www.charitydynamics.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/09/AdamKaye-Team.jpg",
      "color" : "red",
      "projectDescription" : "Currently working on...",
      "email": "test@email.com",
      "yahoo" : "yahooIM",
      "upcoming" : "PTO / WFH / OOO"
    }
```

Comment: Great job adding a well-formed question here! Also, welcome to Stack Overflow. : )  One tiny detail to improve on this:  Is all of this absolutely necessary to reproduce and understand the problem set? I'm having a hard time deciding which parts are relevant to your question and which are superfluous. Reducing the problem set will make it easier and faster to get to the core issue. See [creating an mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1):

In dashboard.js:

```
var currentUser = $rootScope.currentUser;
$scope.isCurrentUser = function() {
  return currentUser.id == $scope.member.id;
};
```

In dashboard.html you can then use conditional code blocks:

```
<input ng-disabled="!isCurrentUser()">

<form ng-if="isCurrentUser()">
```

Or similar.

Comment: Hey, I appreciate the lead, but I still can't figure it out. I tried including the isCurrentUser() in my Dashboard controller, but any property I attach to $rootScope.currentUser is giving me an 'undefined' in the console, properties such as $rootScope.currentUser.id or $rootScope.currentUser.email.
    
However, when I check out the object in the console using '$rootScope = angular.element(document).scope()', I can see those properties are there. Any other suggestions?

Comment: Could you create a plunkr or jsfiddle? Maybe angular loses the reference to the object when using $rootScope.currentUser.id. Try my updated anwer.

Comment: Ugh, correction - I originally commented that it worked but I was wrong. I'll get it onto plunker as soon as I can. Thanks for helping Jesse.

Comment: Here's a link to the [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/GlDYqEWCmacaAtiXgXV2?p=preview) with the necessary files. I am running this app with Gulp tasks, so the Plunker won't load the actual app... but you can see more of my code there. Thanks Jesse

Comment: Jesse, I guess I should explain how it's not working. First of all, the console log is clean, so we can assume there aren't any errors in code. However, when I am logged in as (for example) User 3 with $id of 3, I cannot edit the dashboard.html forms for User 3. So, basically, I can log in as me, but can't edit me.